# Add one month to date

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a spreadsheet in which i am trying to create a table and send it word. That part works fine. The only issue i'm having its concerning the date . I have a date in cell B1(10/04/2020).I must add one month to that date. I am using the DateAdd function.When i execute  VBA, i get an error 'object does not support this property or method on this line **objTbl.Cell(T, 3).Value = DateAdd("m", 1, Range("B1").Value)**

My codes are as follows :-

```
Sub CreateTableInWord()
Dim objWord As Object
Dim objDoc As Object
Dim objTbl As Object
Dim objRow As Object
Dim objCol As Object
Dim lngCols As Long
Dim lngRows As Long
Dim I As Long

    lngCols = 6
    lngRows = 62

    Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")

    objWord.Visible = True

    Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Add(DocumentType:=0)

    Set objTbl = objDoc.Tables.Add(Range:=objDoc.Paragraphs(1).Range, NumRows:=lngRows, NumColumns:=lngCols)

    Set objRow = objTbl.Rows(1)


   objTbl.Cell(1, 1).Range.Text = "Instal No"
   objTbl.Cell(1, 1).Range.Bold = True
   objTbl.Cell(1, 2).Range.Text = "Amt(Rs)"
   objTbl.Cell(1, 2).Range.Bold = True
   objTbl.Cell(1, 3).Range.Text = "Due Date"
   objTbl.Cell(2, 3) = Range("B1").Value
   objTbl.Cell(1, 3).Range.Bold = True
   objTbl.Cell(1, 4).Range.Text = "Instal No"
   objTbl.Cell(1, 4).Range.Bold = True
   objTbl.Cell(1, 5).Range.Text = "Amt(Rs)"
   objTbl.Cell(1, 5).Range.Bold = True
   objTbl.Cell(1, 6).Range.Text = "Due Date"
   objTbl.Cell(1, 6).Range.Bold = True
   objTbl.Range.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphCenter
    For I = 2 To lngRows

    ' For j = 1 To intNoOfColumns

  objTbl.Cell(I, 1).Range = I - 1

     Next

   For S = 2 To lngRows

  objTbl.Cell(S, 2) = Range("A1").Value

    Next

For T = 2 To lngRows

objTbl.Cell(T, 3).Value = DateAdd("m", 1, Range("B1").Value)

Next T


    Set objCol = Nothing

    Set objRow = Nothing

    Set objDoc = Nothing

    Set objWord = Nothing

End Sub
```

Your help will be highly appreciated

regards

rakesh

Comment: A Word [`Cell`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.cell) doesn't have a `.Value`.

Comment: Ok i am going to remove the .value and see it if it works

Comment: Cross-posted at: https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/add-one-month-to-date-excel-vba.1132954. For cross-posting etiquette, please read: excelguru.ca/content.php?184

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
objTbl.Cell(T, 3).Range.Text = DateAdd("m", 1, Range("B1").Value)
```

PS: Most of your code would be unnecessary if you used a Word template with the boilerplate content already present.

Comment: Thanks. I have made the necessary amendments and it partially works. It fills  the column. My date  in Cell B1 is  10/04/2020(dd/mm/yyyy).When I execute  VBA, the results are as follows :- 11/04/2020, 11/04/2020, 11/04/2020 and it goes like that. It only adds  one day to the date . Results  should have been 10/04/2020,10/05/2020,10/06/2020 and so on

Comment: That suggests cell B1 is actually using a mm/dd/yyyy format (i.e. *not* dd/mm/yyyy) and you're continually referencing B1 but are only ever adding 1 month to that cell's value. If you want to increment the dates, you need to either update the value in B1 or increment the '1' in the DateAdd Function at each iteration.

Comment: objTbl.Cell(T, 3).Text= Format(DateAdd("m", T - 2, Range("B1").Value) , "dd/mm/yyyy")

Comment: i have changed my line code as per above and my cell B1 to 13/05/2020(dd/mm/yyyy) it works one month is added to the date. But when i change the date to 01/05/2020 it changes to 1/5/2020 in cell B1 and get the following output 1/5/2020
05/02/2020
05/03/2020
05/04/2020
05/05/2020

Comment: I have change the format my date to dd/mm/yyyy in Cell B1 and have to change For T = 3 To lngRows to For T = 2 To lngRows

Comment: «when i change the date to 01/05/2020 it changes to 1/5/2020 in cell B1» Clearly, you still need to correct your date format in Excel.